# MongoDB - Select from database A documents which exists in database B without join

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to select documents from one database which ids are present in other database. This query won't do:

```
db.getCollection('A').aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "B",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "bid",
    }
  }
])
```

Because it just joins the documents which exists in B and it still gives me documents which does not present in B (the "bid" field is empty). I also want to get the original A document without additional fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$lookup` is actually correct way to do. You just need 1 more [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#definition) to filter out unmatched document and `$project` to keep the original schema in collection A.

```
db.A.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "B",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "bid"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$bid"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      // remove the lookup field
      bid: false
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d-RblxUZpT0) for your reference.